# Why are CLR Types derived from generics not supported in SQL Server 2008 and later?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, generics, sql-server-2012

The following code implements an UDT which derives from a generic (SortedDictionary):

```
[Serializable]
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedType(Format.UserDefined, MaxByteSize = 8000)]
public class udtMassSpectra : SortedDictionary<float, float>, INullable, IBinarySerialize, ICloneable, IDisposable
{
...
}
```

Creating the type (T-SQL):

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.udtMassSpectra EXTERNAL NAME MassSpectra.udtMassSpectra;
```

throws an exception:

> Msg 10331, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Type 'udtMassSpectra' in assembly
>   'MassSpectra' derives from a generic type which is not supported for a
>   CLR Type.

What is the reason? Is there any workaround other than hiding the base class within a private member? This code works fine on a SQL-Server 2005.

Comment: I hope they will answer. http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/737635/cannot-create-udt-which-derives-from-a-generic-on-sql-server-2008

Comment: I think the fact it worked in 2005 and the report hasn't been closed on Connect indicates that you may have stumbled across an old fashioned bug.

Answer (score 1):

One other suggestion:

> Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested
>   or generic

PS:

As far as "worked on MSSQL 2005 but not MSSQL 2008" -  I quote Tom Petty: "You got lucky, babe!" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with UDTs, but maybe the problem is that float isn't able to represent SQL-Server's NULL value.

I did some research and found this [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/SQL2008R2TrainingKit/CLR/NullableTypesDemo)

Comment: `udtMassSpectra` implements `bool IsNull` from the interface [`INullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.inullable.aspx). So the type is able to represent SQL-Server's Null value. Maybe I should clarify that this code runs fine on a SQL Server 2005 but fails on later versions of SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You can very simply work around this limitation by storing an instance of `SortedDictionary<float, float>` in your UDT.

Just out of curiosity, I would like to see how a generic class is instantiated in a T-SQL context, as a column datatype, variable, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned this workaround allready in my question. Use the type like this, pretty standard I think: `CREATE TABLE #test(
 [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [spectrum_freetext] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [spectrum_binary] [dbo].[udtMassSpectra] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]` or like this `select udtMassSpectra::Parse('669.2344-745.5663|801.7557-880.7614|889.2369-978.5437|1016.6830-12|').ToString() as LCMS`